# Entering Paypal Live Environment on Android App

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I integrated the Paypal SDK onto my android app, I tested the integration on sandbox mode, and everything worked perfectly! However, when I was reading the [Paypal Documentation for going live](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/) it says that I should get some API credentials, but when I click the link It only gives me the option to get API credentials for websites not android applications.

Am I looking on the wrong section of the Paypal documentation? Should I just change .environment`(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)` to `.environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)` ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change only two lines
first is change `PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` to `PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION`
like this

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
```

and you have to change client id `private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AZxhbBz4VbxfWk-Fo5bGqgV7uANh-w4qkiqB0rZysThYu2y_iSPZeVnU8PzgU-CsFu6Iremo7SlhISMt";`